# I can't setup a react apollo mongodb app => resolvers with mongo / mongoose / NO METEOR

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, mongoose, apollo

I'm currently **learning Apollo**, I'm a front end developer ( angular 1.5 over half a year for the background )
I have a very little experience with mongodb, and also with apollo ( trhough a meteor app )

I've read several times the Apollo doc, parsed Google with the keywords apollo, react, mongodb, resolvers, with various combinations ... ( no results )

I need to build a little **React** app (POC) which handle **query, mutations, and subscriptions** which would persist data with mongodb ( or another DB, I indicate this one since this is only one I've worked with so far ).

I **cannot** use **Meteor**.

My problem is that I can't find proper examples for **graphql resolver** working with mongo for all cases I need ( query, sub, mutate).

Would you have some **boilerplate** to provide , to help me to understand the mecanism ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to go through some tutorials. You could look at the githunt project. It is a apollo-graphql implementation with queries, mutations and subscriptions. It does not use a mongoDB, but this should be an easy change.

server: https://github.com/apollographql/GitHunt-API/tree/master/api

client: https://github.com/apollographql/GitHunt-React

Cheers

Comment: I did try, but some pieces wor rewritting were upon my current skills.
I posted a answer which points to a boilerplate to start ( not from me ) for people who might need the same piece of code to start properly.
Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

I think [graphqly](https://github.com/anhldbk/graphqly) is the answer for you.

```
import graphly from "graphqly";

const gBuilder = graphly.createBuilder();

// define types, inputs ... (in any order)
gBuilder.type("Products").implements("List").def(`
  products: [Product]!
`);

gBuilder.type("Product").def(`
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  link: String
  price: Int
`);

// we're too lazy to define a separate input, so we can `extend` other structure
gBuilder.input("ProductInput").ext("Product");

gBuilder.enum("ProductOrder").def(`
  PRICE_DESCENDING
  PRICE_ASCENDING
  NEWEST
`);

// define interface `List`
gBuilder.iface("List").def(`
  total: Int!,
  offset: Int!,
  limit: Int!,
  # number of items actually in this window
  size: Int!
`);


gBuilder.query(`
  products(limit: Int = 20, offset: Int = 0, filter: ProductFilter): Products
`)
.resolve((root, args, context) => {
  // your resolver here
  // `this` is binded to the current Query instance
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I was search for something more complete ( see my answer ).
But thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a good start for server only part with mongo / mongoose :

https://github.com/khadorkin/apollo-server-mongoose

I've enhanced this, I'll provide a link to the github repo in a few days.

Here is the repo.
Still work to be done, specially about subscriptions, but it might be a good start

[Link to Github repo](https://github.com/hyphaene/apollo-server-mongoose)